# On Running the test suite: Runs the test suite shows test passed Notification but displays "Empty Suite"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pycharm, webdriver

Here's my code but it shows no Tests found, and prints Empty Suite

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\win\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\win\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def Test(self):
        self.driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("admin123")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("txtUsername").send_keys("Admin")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
        time.sleep(2)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
        print("Test Complete")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I wrote this code, but on running my Test Suite it displays as follows:

```
Testing started at 2:47 PM ...
C:\PycharmProject\OrangeHRM\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target LoginTest.LoginTest
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest LoginTest.LoginTest in C:\PycharmProject\OrangeHRM\ScriptsDemo\Tests



Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0

No Tests were found

Empty suite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [unittest library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) exists a naming convention that all the tests start with 'test', this informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

You have to change your 'Test' method to 'test'

Comment: Well it worked for me,
But I also wanted to know that, it opens two web-browser.
What's the reason behind it ?

Comment: setUpClass executes one time before the execution of the test suite this method provides one instance of the webdriver storage in the variable ⇾ cls.driver


When you assign the driver variable after creating the class you are creating another driver so that's why you see 2 webdrivers.

Just delete the first one.